# How to prevent error: element is not currently intractable and may not be manipulated?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using C# I was trying to replace a value from input box like this

> ```
>         for (int second = 0; ; second++)
>         {
>             if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
>             if (second > 15) break;
>
>          Thread.Sleep(1000);
>       }
>
>         driver.FindElement(By.Id("input1")).Clear();
>         driver.FindElement(By.Id("input1")).SendKeys(xxxx");
> ```

but I get error "element is not currently intractable and may not be manipulated" on the clear() line , why is that although I wait until page load ?

HTML

```
<input class="valid" id="input1" name="input1" value="http://dddd" nametemplate="url_to_5D" type="text">
```

Comment: Which driver are you using? Maybe ghostdriver/phantomJS?

Comment: just Firefox with webdriver

Comment: Is it interactable when you use only SendKeys without Clear()? And just one note, you are not waiting for page to be loaded, you are just waiting 15 seconds no matter if page is loaded or not.

Comment: @acikojevic if I comment clear() in sendkeys line I get element is not visible. I tried to use solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993 but it never wait it execute instantly

Comment: @Wel please share your HTML in order to find the issue!

Comment: @HappyBird added html

Comment: part of my problem is using FireFox when I switched to Chrome all unexpected results was solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try to wait for it:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("input1")));
```

and then:

```
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys("xxxx");
```

To make your driver wait before any action simply:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

If you use the above code, you can remove all the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` actions.

Comment: I tried that but browser never wait. before these lines I click on a link that open new tab , is there something I should do to make the wait and the element execute on the new opened tab ?

Comment: What do you mean by "never wait"?

Comment: execution does not stop at the wait line and I get the error immediately at the clear() line. "input1" is located on the new opened tab.

Comment: Maybe try `ElementToBeVisible` as this is an input field. I have edited the answer ;)

Comment: Another idea would be the `WindowHandles` as you have multiple tabs. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16816780/4280359).

Comment: tried now to switch to new tab like this:
`driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);` but I get this error:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: I switched tabs now but any reason why `new WebDriverWait` does not pause execution ? the next line in visual studio execute immediately !!

Comment: Because it is not the constructor call that stops it. Only in the next line `wait.Until` is called.

Comment: Thanks alot Grzegorz Górkiewicz I am almost there. Can you please tell a way to wait for number of seconds regardless of element is visible or not ?

Comment: Read up on [implicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and you will know it all ;) Click on csharp to display code samples.

Comment: thanks I get now ExpectedConditions' does not contain a definition for 'ElementToBeVisible' why is that ?

Comment: It should be `ElementExists` instead.

Comment: still does not wait until page load , why is that ?

Comment: see screenshot http://imgur.com/a/MKsfQ why WebDriverWait does not wait ?

Comment: `Manage` does not wait either !! please advise

Comment: My theory would be that this element is disabled and JavaScript is needed to enable it. Not a waiting issue anymore.

Comment: I was able to make clear() work by adding `WebDriverWait` before `driver.SwitchTo()` and another one after it !!!

Comment: So probably the site in another tab did not load properly. Waits are almost always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Grzegorz Górkiewicz, bounty will be released after 22 hours ! plz keep your eye on selenium tag I am sure I will create other questions.

Comment: See you soon #selenium.